# Rotating individual bones in Python not working

Tags: python, armature, bones

At the end of a script, I need to disconnect all the bones in my armature and rotate them 90 degrees to match what Unreal expects for the joints. I can't seem to get this to work in Python, though.

Here's what I have:

```
#disconnect the bones so the joints can be rotated to match ue
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.armature.parent_clear(type='DISCONNECT')

#this isn't working, it still pivots on the median
bpy.ops.armature.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS'
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='Z', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

It does disconnect the bones, but it does not rotate them around their individual origins. It rotates them around the median like normal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes I can confirm the INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS is not working in this case... I wonder why.